# Get path of a node from xml column

Tags: sql-server, xml

Is it possible to get the path of a node as a string with an sql command from a xml-typed column in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Something like this:

```
select xcolumn.path('//somenode1[@id="1234"]') as result from xtable
```

or

```
select xcolumn.query('path(//somenode1[@id="1234"]);') as result from xtable
```

Comment: `//somenode1[@id="1234"]` is already a path to that node. What else do you need?

Comment: Presumably the OP would like a fully qualified path.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way built into XPath or XQuery.

I did find a JavaScript implementation of an algorithm that will return the path of a node, given the document that the node is part of.  Perhaps you could create a T-SQL UDF that could implement the same logic:

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/get-xpath-string-expression

Other people have pointed out that Firebug is open-source and has logic to do this, so that algorithm is available.  But, again, that's not in T-SQL.

Comment: Well, I doubt that it would be fast, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Siggi If SQL Server supported using the `ancestors` or `ancestors-or-self` axis in XPath, this would be very easy to do, but it doesn't.  If you have the option of writing a CLR function, it would be very easy to do.